# Creating plan via MS Graph API returns empty ODataError

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I'm trying to create a *plan* inside a *group* using the Microsoft Graph SDK, but the request fails.

I'm able to get a list of groups, and a list of plans within a group, but when I copy-paste the code from the [documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example), I receive an ODataError without any exception details or even a meaningful message.

This is the code I'm using:

```
private async Task<PlannerPlan?> CreatePlan(Guid id, string planName)
{
    var requestBody = new PlannerPlan
                      {
                          Container = new PlannerPlanContainer
                                      {
                                          Url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}"
                                      },
                          Title = planName
                      };

    var graphClient = GetGraphClient();
    try
    {
        return await graphClient.Planner.Plans.PostAsync(requestBody);
    }
    catch (Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError oDataError)
    {
        var error = oDataError.Error;

        throw;
    }
}
```

The `id` is taken directly from the group which was obtained by calling...

```
await graphClient.Groups.GetAsync();
```

I've also tried specifying the group ID (as `ContainerId`) and the container type (`Type = PlannerContainerType.Group`) in the `PlannerPlan` object, but this makes no difference.

This is the response from the Graph API:

[image]

The authentication takes place through an Azure *app registration*, which has been granted the following permissions:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I'm unable to create the plan?

Comment: Could you try changing your container URL from beta endpoint to **v1.0** endpoint by replacing beta with _v1.0_ like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one Azure AD application and granted API permissions of **Application** type like this:

[image]

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran your code with `/beta` in container URL like this:

```cs
private async Task<PlannerPlan?> CreatePlan(Guid id, string planName)
{
    var requestBody = new PlannerPlan
                      {
                          Container = new PlannerPlanContainer
                                      {
                                          Url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}"
                                      },
                          Title = planName
                      };

    var graphClient = GetGraphClient();
    try
    {
        return await graphClient.Planner.Plans.PostAsync(requestBody);
    }
    catch (Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError oDataError)
    {
        var error = oDataError.Error;

        throw;
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make use of `v1.0` endpoint by modifying your code that is the correct **containerUrl** to specify path to group like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using System;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var groupId = "groupId"; // Group ID where you want to create the plan

            var createdPlan = await CreatePlan(new Guid(groupId), "Demo Plan1", graphClient);

            Console.WriteLine($"Plan Title: {createdPlan.Title}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Plan ID: {createdPlan.Id}");
        }
        catch (Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError oDataError)
        {
            var error = oDataError.Error;

            Console.WriteLine(error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<PlannerPlan?> CreatePlan(Guid id, string planName, GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        var requestBody = new PlannerPlan
        {
            Container = new PlannerPlanContainer
            {
                Url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}"
            },
            Title = planName
        };

        try
        {
            return await graphClient.Planner.Plans.PostAsync(requestBody);
        }
        catch (Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError oDataError)
        {
            var error = oDataError.Error;

            throw; // Rethrow the exception to propagate it
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[plannerPlanContainer resource type - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannerplancontainer?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are using `v1.0`, but the example has `/beta` endpoint in the body instead of the correct `v1.0`.

```
var requestBody = new PlannerPlan
{
    Container = new PlannerPlanContainer
    {
        Url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}"
    },
    Title = planName
};
```